# The space of $\ell_2$ sequences $(a_n)$ such that $\sum \frac{a_n}{\sqrt n}=0$ is dense in $\ell_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I'm learning functional analysis from "Functional Analysis an Introduction" of Yuli Eidelman, Vitali Milman, Antonis Tsolomitis, and I encountered the following question:

> Show that $E=${${(a_n)_{n=1} ^\infty\in l_2 | \sum \frac{a_n}{\sqrt n}=0}$} is dense in $l_2$.

I didn't manage to solve it. Thought about finding a complete system inside of $E$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the following linear functional

$$f:l^{2}\to \mathbb{K}$$ given by $f((x_{n}))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Use Comparison test to show that the map is well defined for, $\frac{x_{n}^{2}}{n}\leq x_{n}^{2}$

Use Riesz's Representation theorem to show that this linear functional is not continuos. Hence $Ker(f)$ is dense in $l^{2}$.

Comment: why? $f((1/n))=(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}})$, which belongs to $l^{2}$ isn't it? By the way to show that the function is well-defined use the comparison test.

Comment: My example was bad. But what about $(a_n)=\frac {1}{logn\sqrt {n}}$?

Comment: Aren't you convinced about the comparison test?

Comment: Even if I'm not convinced, I can use the fact that $f$ is defined on $s^*$ (the space of sequences with finite support) and $s^*$ is dense in $E$. So I'm good anyway, thanks.